# What is the fastest way to detect when two timestamps produce the same local time in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, optimization, dst

The UNIX timestamps `1289106000` and `1289109600` both represent `2010-11-07T01:00:00` in the US-East EST/EDT timezone, as a result of daylight savings time.  I'm creating a dictionary-like object, keyed on timestamp, that needs to map any such pairs to the same value.

Additionally, as much as we want to avoid premature optimization, I happen to know that this operation is performed in an extremely tight loop.  Any solution must be faster than using `fromtimestamp` to obtain the local time for each timestamp.

Is there a way to structure my object's back-end storage, or build some sort of lookup table in advance, that makes this possible?

Comment: +1 for your question... and your username ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a table, stretching as far into the past or future as you wish, with the overlapping hour for each year. It's easy to convert the timestamp to an approximate year with a simple division. Look up the tuple (start_leap_hour,end_leap_hour) from the year; if the timestamp is between them, subtract an hour.

Comment: How might I construct that table (specific to the timezone of the machine running the code) in Python?

Comment: @DNS, check out pytz: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/. I may come back to update the answer later, don't have enough time at the moment. The documentation doesn't give up how to get the transition dates from the database, but it does make me think of an alternate solution...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding how one might generate a table of DST critical times:

This generates the datetimes when Daylight Savings Time "fall back" occurs:

```
import datetime as dt
import time
import itertools

def fall_dst_boundaries(date=None):
    '''
    Generates the datetimes when Daylight Savings Time "fall back" occurs after date.
    '''
    if date is None:
        date=dt.datetime.now()
    timestamp=time.mktime(date.timetuple())//3600 * 3600
    previous_date=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    while True:
        timestamp+=3600
        date=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
        if date==previous_date:
            yield date
        previous_date=date

for date in itertools.islice(fall_dst_boundaries(dt.datetime(1980,1,1)),15):
    print(date)
```

yields:

```
1980-10-26 01:00:00
1981-10-25 01:00:00
1982-10-31 01:00:00
1983-10-30 01:00:00
1984-10-28 01:00:00
1985-10-27 01:00:00
1986-10-26 01:00:00
1987-10-25 01:00:00
1988-10-30 01:00:00
1989-10-29 01:00:00
1990-10-28 01:00:00
1991-10-27 01:00:00
1992-10-25 01:00:00
1993-10-31 01:00:00
1994-10-30 01:00:00
```

PS. DST ends at 2am, but the hour the gets repeated is 1am.

---

To generate both the "fall back" and "spring forward" datetimes, you could use something like this:

```
def DST_boundaries(date=None):
    '''
    Generates the datetimes when Daylight Savings Time "fall back" or "spring
    forward" occurs after date.
    '''
    if date is None:
        date=dt.datetime.now()
    timestamp=time.mktime(date.timetuple())//3600 * 3600 + 3599
    previous_date=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    while True:
        timestamp+=3600
        date=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
        if date==previous_date or date.hour-previous_date.hour>1:
            yield previous_date
        previous_date=date
```